# dynamic table in php from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

есть php code

```
function get_shows(){
        $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
        if(!$conn){
            die('can not connect to server!');
        }
        $db = mysql_select_db('testing',$conn);
        if(!$db){
            die('can not connect to database!');
        }
        $query = "select * from shows";
        $data = mysql_query($query,$conn);
        
        $shows = array();
        
        while($object=mysql_fetch_object($data)){
            $shows[] 
            $shows[] = $object;
        }
        mysql_close($conn);
        return $shows;
    }
    
    function get_table(){
        
        $table_str = '<table id=progContainer >';
        $shows = get_shows();
        
        foreach($shows as $shows){
            $table_str.='<tr>';
            $table_str.='<td>'.(date($shows->timeStart)).'-'.($shows->timeEnd).'</td><td>'.$shows->title.'</td>';
            $table_str.='</tr>';
        }
        $table_str.= '</table>';
        return $table_str;
    }
```

и не большая проблема что на сервере timeStart и timeEnd я поставил type - time  и на выходе выходит

> 17:00:00.000000-18:00:00.000000  live u
>
> 21:00:00.000000-21:30:00.000000  stand up
>
> 21:30:00.000000-21:40:00.000000    like u
>
> 21:50:00.000000-00:00:00.000000    kill
>
> 00:00:00.000000-00:50:00.000000    singer
>
> 00:50:00.000000-02:00:00.000000    sing to u

как можно убрать нули что-бы было:

> 17:00-18:00  live u
>
> 21:00-21:30  stand up
>
> 21:30-21:40    like u
>
> 21:50-00:00    kill
>
> 00:00-00:50    singer
>
> 00:50-02:00    sing to u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
date("H:i",$shows->timeStart)
date("H:i",$shows->timeEnd)
```

EDITED:

Попробуйте в запросе к базе данных использовать TIME_FORMAT:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(foo_hour, '%H:%i')
FROM bar
```

Вот похожий на ваш случай пример:

```
    $query = "
          SELECT %колонка1%, %колонка2%, TIME_FORMAT('timeStart', '%H:%i') as timeStart
          FROM shows";
```

EDITED2:
Я создал тестовую таблицу такого вида:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
         id INT,
         time TIME
       );
INSERT INTO example VALUES (1,'08:12'), (2,'15:03'), (3,'23:57');
```

Теперь получаю данные оттуда с TIME_FORMAT, который я советую вам использовать:

```
SELECT id, time, TIME_FORMAT(time, '%H:%i') as timeStart from example
```

Вот результат:

```
id  time                        timeStart
1   January, 01 1970 08:12:00   08:12
2   January, 01 1970 15:03:00   15:03
3   January, 01 1970 23:57:00   23:57
```

Тоесть ответ этого TIME_FORMAT какраз такой, какой вы и ожидаете.
Ну и в php используете `date("H:i",$shows->timeStart)`, что-бы быть уже полностью увереным в правильности вывода.

Comment: нет не получается !

Comment: А что получается? Не могли бы распечатать $shows->timeStart  и date("H:i",$shows->timeStart) ?

Comment: (date($shows->timeStart)).'-'.($shows->timeEnd)    ошибкой выходит и всё равно что показывала так и показывает !

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста, что за ошибка и что выводит date("H:i",$shows->timeStart). Кстати, у вас во втором случае нет функции data, только $shows->timeEnd. Это не правильно.

Comment: я немного ошибся сдесь я писам так без data 
foreach($shows as $shows){
            $table_str.='<tr>';
            $table_str.='<td>'.($shows->timeStart).'-'.($shows-timeEnd).'</td><td>'.$shows->title.'</td>';>            $table_str.='</tr>';
        }

и всё равно не выходит я думаю надо всё переделать !

Comment: Извините пожалуйста, я совершенно не понимаю вас без знаков пунктуации. Для нахождения ответа на вопрос мне надо увидеть, что распечатывается на date("H:i",$shows->timeStart) и, что за ошибка появляется.

Comment: вот что выходит 
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\webstarlive_test\test.php on line 148

Comment: Добавил возможное решение для форматирования даты в своем ответе.

Comment: А в строчке 148 что написано?

Comment: $table_str.='<td>'.(date("H:i",$shows->timeStart)).'-'.(date("H:i",$shows->timeEnd)).'</td><td>'.$shows->title.'</td>';

Comment: Попробуйте так: $query = "select %колонка1%, %колонка2%, TIME_FORMAT("timeStart", '%H:%i') as timeStart, %и так далее%  from shows"

Comment: нет извините но нет !

Comment: надо подумать и переписать всю php и mysql как я думаю ! точно что-то не так сделал !

Comment: Не за что извинятся! :) Тогда как вы думаете решать проблему? А вы не могли бы запустить у себя в базе такой запрос: SELECT  TIME_FORMAT(timeStart, '%H:%i') as timeStart  FROM shows       и сказать, что получается? Не через php, а напрямую в базе...

Comment: Добавил в своем ответе маленький пример. Гляньте, будте любезны...

Comment: большое спасибо всё сработало !